# GLSL using structs as uniform blocks

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have a struct type, that I want to pass in as a uniform. Is it possible to do that with UBO?

```
struct LightParams {
  // ...
};
uniform LightParams uLight;
```

Apparently that does not declare it as a uniform block, and declares a regular uniform instead (and I have to assign individual members via `glGetUniformLocation("uLight.position")` apparently?)

Another option would be to use

```
uniform LightBlock {
  LightParams uLight;
};
```

But then the uniform block name would be `LightBlock` and not `uLight`, which is sort of confusing.

Is there really no concept of using structs as blocks?

Comment: I fail to see your issue here. You'll access this struct in the s `uLight`, just as in the ordinary uniform declaration.

Comment: "*Is there really no concept of using structs as blocks?*" ... why would there need to be?

Comment: @derhass shader sees it as `uLight`, but `getUniformBlockIndex("uLight")` is invalid.

Comment: Well, realistically, you want to set the UBO binding directly with `layout(binding=...)` anyway. It is really a moot point.

Comment: Well, ideally I wanted to define a uniform block with some variables, and then pass it to a function as a single argument (it looks like a struct!), but apparently that's not possible. Putting a struct inside a uniform block is actually different from a block with individual variables inside it, because it adds extra padding to match `vec4` alignment as per `std140`.